# Maintain ordering of characters if there is no id (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following

**Chars**

```
A
C
W
B
J
M
```

How can I insert some sequential numbers so that after insertion of the numbers the order of characters will not change?

I mean if I use row_number(), the output Character order is changing like

```
select 
ROW_NUMBER() over(order by chars) as id,
t.* from @t t
```

**Output:**

**id    chars**

```
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   J
5   M
6   W
```

My desired expectation is

**id    chars**

```
1   A
2   C
3   W
4   B
5   J
6   M
```

Also, I cannot use any identity field like `id int identity` because I am in the middle of a query and I need to maintain a inner join for achieving something.

I hope I do make myself clear.

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does the ordering of the CHARs as A C W B J M come from?

Comment: you need some form of an ID or a date/timestamp to get order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no implicit ordering of rows in SQL**.   If some ordering is desired, be it order in which items were inserted or any other order, it must be supported by a *user-defined* column.

In other words, the SQL standard doesn't require the SQL implementations to maintain any order.  On the other hand the ORDER BY clause in a SELECT statement can be used to specify the desired order, but such ordering is supported by the values in a particular (again, user defined) column.

This user defined column may well be an auto-incremented column for which SQL assigns incremental (or otherwise) values to, and this may be what you need.

Maybe something like...

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
   InsertID smallint IDENTITY(1,1),
   OneChar  CHAR(1),
   SomeOtherField VARCHAR(20)
   -- ... etc.
)

INSERT INTO myTable (OneChar, SomeOtherField) VALUES ('A', 'Alpha')
INSERT INTO myTable (OneChar, SomeOtherField) VALUES ('W', 'Whiskey')
INSERT INTO myTable (OneChar, SomeOtherField) VALUES ('B', 'Bravo')
-- ... etc.

SELECT OneChar
FROM myTable
ORDER BY InsertId

'A'
'W'
'B'
--...
```

Comment: Hi, infact that is what I said that the result what I have presented here is an outcome of some query. I don't have a table as such where those data are present. Henceforth, I cannot use identity column.

Comment: You can use something like `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GETDATE()) AS id, t.* FROM @t t`   This is a trick, for GetDate() only gets evaluated once anyway, and shouldn't change the implied order of this @t thing...  But as said if this order hasn't been explicitly required you shouldn't rely on it.  

t.* from @t t

Comment: thanks man... even i was thinking to do like select 1 as rn,col from  table and then applyinh row_number(over rn) to achieve the same.